# How do you store values from user inputted data?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-spinner, android-statusbar

I have created a spinner to display categories that the user can choose from and when it's selected I want the option to be saved somewhere.

I was wondering what could I use to store the values in for Kotlin, i've seen tutorials using firebase but none in relation to Kotlin that I could see, would firebase be the only storage you could use or is there simpler ways to store the value as it would be preferred

activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="75dp"
                 android:id="@+id/statusFilter"
                 android:layout_gravity="center" />

  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:onClick="btnAdd"
                    android:text="@string/button_addLetter"
                    android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary_variant"
                    android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Main Activity

```
class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AnkoLogger, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    var letter = NewsItemModel()
    lateinit var app : MainApp
    var edit = false
    val IMAGE_REQUEST = 1

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_letter)
        app = application as MainApp
   


 val dropDownList = arrayOf("Latest", "Coronavirus Updates", "Crime", "Traffic and Travel", "Business", "Politics", "Weather", "Education", "Health")

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dropDownList)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
        statusFilter.adapter = adapter
        statusFilter.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
   val preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 1){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",1).apply() //Puts 0, 1,2,3 with key "POSITION_KEY"
                }

                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 2){
                    preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",2).apply() //Puts 0, 1,2,3 with key "POSITION_KEY"
                }
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 3){
                    condition3()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 4){
                    condition4()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 5){
                    condition5()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 6){
                    condition6()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 7){
                    condition7()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 8){
                    condition8()
                }
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 9){
                    condition9()
                }
            }

        private fun condition1(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",1)
            }
            private fun condition2(){
                preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",2)
            }
            private fun condition3(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            private fun condition4(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            private fun condition5(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            private fun condition6(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            private fun condition7(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            private fun condition8(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            private fun condition9(){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected Item: " + statusFilter.selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }




fun btnAdd(view: View) {
        val pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = pref.edit()

        editor.putString("SELECTION", statusFilter.toString())

        editor.commit()

        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Saved test1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

 val pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val SELECTION = pref.getString("SELECTION", "")
        statusFilter(SELECTION)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean locally?

SharedPreferences is the way to go, it seems like yours isn't working/implemented yet:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

You probably only care about the position that is selected, so replace all of the conditions with this:

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
      preferences.edit().putInt("POSITION_KEY",position).apply() //Puts 0, 1,2,3 with key "POSITION_KEY"
}
```

And then define that preferences variable before using it (like you already did with getPreferences, see the link)

You can then retrieve it with `preferences.getInt("POSITION_KEY",0)` where 0 is the default value when the key hasn't been defined/put yet

Comment: Yes locally, would it be as how I did in the post? I updated it with my attempt under the conditions.

Comment: Is that the correct way so I can implement the rest, it's just that the conditions are  no longer used which makes me feel I might be implementing ur solution wrong

Answer (score 0):

Well. There are quite a few different ways of storing data in Android, all have their good and bad points.

FireBase might be good for storing data remotely.
Room might be good for storing it locally ([Android Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room?gclid=Cj0KCQjwvr6EBhDOARIsAPpqUPHwtcn7P-u3uaadp11vuCO3YFi-xwjxCvHIMx05fYKRhZY9XqwiopIaAm0FEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds))
Or if it is simple data (like user preferences or settings) then maybe UserPreferences might be what you want ([Android - Key Value Data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences))

Google provides quite a lot of information, but sometimes it is hard to know what to look for.
You might want to read through some of this: [Android Topics - Data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data)
Good luck :-)

P.S. You might want to check out "when" in Kotlin: [Try When](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Basic%20syntax%20walk-through/Use%20when/Use%20when.kt)

Then you can rewrite

```
                if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 1){
                condition1()
            }
            if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 2){
                condition2()
            }
            if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 3){
                condition3()
            }
            if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 4){
                condition4()
            }
            if(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition == 5){
                condition5()
            }
```

as something like..

```
when(statusFilter.selectedItemPosition) {
   1 -> condition1()
   2 -> condition2()
   3 -> condition3()
... etc ...
}
```

Much less typing :-)

Comment: Thanks will definitely give a try, I was thinking about locally storing, easiest way to go.

Comment: Also would you know why my statusFilter is getting an error within my code at the bottom val pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

within my statusFilter(SELECTION) is getting an error and in a tutorial on how to store in sharedPreferences this was a function included but is not compiling for me